# c# regular expressions, allow numbers and letters only not working

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, expression

I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

I need a regular expression that allows only numbers and letters, not spaces or ",.;:~^" anything like that.  Plain numbers and letters.

Another thing: 2 characters can't repeat consecutively.

So I can have 123123 but not 1123456.

I got as far as to:

```
Regex ER1 = new Regex(@"(.)\\1", RegexOptions.None);

Regex ER2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I could not make it all in one expression and I still have some characters passing through.

Here is my entire code for testing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        Regex ER1 = new Regex(@"(.)\\1", RegexOptions.None);

        Regex ER2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (!ER1.IsMatch(input) && ER2.IsMatch(input))
            Console.WriteLine( "Casou");
        else
            Console.WriteLine( "Não casou");

            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I find these expressions quite complex and I'd be really happy to have some help with this.

Comment: It sounds like your making _evil_ password restrictions.  Don't do that.

Comment: Well, I actually have no idea how the code is going to be used. My boss needs it. I do it. Simple as that :D
But if I were to guess now that you mentioned it, I kinda think that's what he needs it for. LOL how did you know man?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
@"^(([0-9A-Z])(?!\2))*$"
```

Explained:

```
^               start of string
 (              group #1
   ([0-9A-Z])   a digit or a letter (group #2)
   (?!\2)      not followed by what is captured by second group ([0-9A-Z])
 )*             any number of these
$               end of string
```

The `?!` group is called a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

(*LastCoder's* expression is equivalent)

Comment: You have an extra backslash

Comment: Oops, started with an ordinary string

Comment: Yours didn't work either man. 

Regex ER = new Regex(@"^(([0-9A-Z])(?!\\2))*$", RegexOptions.None);


Does not let me type letters.

But thanks anyways

Comment: Oh man. OK. This one works perfectly now. As far as I can tell.
Thank you so much.
I guess I'm gonna earn a golden star at work now hahahaha.
Thank you all for your efforts, time and help.
Regards from Brazil.
Cesar. ;)

Comment: I'd like to ask for an extra help.
How can I use that expression in an attribute?
Such as: [RegularExpression(@"^(([0-9A-Z])(?!\2))*$"]

Comment: Sorry, I'm here for the regexps, not the C#. You do have unbalanced parentheses though in your comment: `[RegularExpression(@"^(([0-9A-Z])(?!\2))*$")]`

Comment: Yeah. That's OK. I just removed the rest of the C# code there and took away the other parentheses.
Thank you for your help anyways. =)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
@"^(?:([A-Z0-9])(?!\1))*$"
```

Comment: I tested it this way and it didn't work: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. 
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Regex ER = new Regex(@"^(?:([A-Z0-9])(?!\1))*$", RegexOptions.None);           
            if (ER.IsMatch(input))
                Console.WriteLine( "Casou");
            else
                Console.WriteLine( "Não casou");
                Console.ReadLine();
        }

It does not accepts letter this way. Only numbers. But dots and comas are also blocked.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I got that.
Now this is almost perfect. The only thing missing is the "no-repeat" thing.
For example. If I type 123123 it should pass, but not if I write 1233.
It should not let me repeat 2 characters consecutively.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly in the example I gave above. But I could not make it work as an attribute. Why is that so?
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(([0-9A-Z])(?!\2))*$", ErrorMessage = "Required")]